# Prononciation du mot « jasser »

Tags: prononciation

Selon Wikipedia, « jasser » est une variante orthographique de « yasser » *et se prononce de la même façon*. Ainsi, le « j » se prononce comme un « y ».

**Questions :**

1. D'abord, pourquoi garde-t-on la même prononciation au lieu de prononcer le « j » normalement ?
2. Ensuite, y a-t-il d'autres mots contenant un « j » se prononçant comme un « y » ?

Comment: Il existe deux verbes *jasser*. L'un qui est du français de Suisse et qui se prononce  /ja.se/  et l'autre qui est du français canadien qui se prononce  /ʒa.se/.

Comment: @Laure Je trouve très curieux que certains dictionnaires donnent le sens de « bavarder » à « jasser ». Au Québec, on « jase », on ne « jasse » pas (je n'ai jamais entendu de ma vie « jasser » dans ce contexte).

Comment: [wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/jasser le mentionne) et effectivement on trouve le mot dans de nombreux forums en ligne. C'est certainement une variante orthographique de [jaser](wiktionary http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/jaser) /ʒɑ.ze/ verbe sens 4. Ce serait intéressant de savoir si effectivement les québécois prononce effectivement /ʒa.se/ et /ʒa.ze/.

Comment: Et encore un [sens](http://books.google.fr/books?id=J5JIxO5sBXoC&pg=PA185&dq=%22jasser%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=AMfEU5zYGOK8ygOl74CIDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22jasser%22&f=false) probablement très localisé !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Jasser* c'est jouer au jeu de *jass*.

Le [jass](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jass) /jas/ est un jeu de cartes d'origine germanique très populaire en Suisse alémanique et qu'on trouve aussi sous ce nom là dans certaines régions germanophones (Liechtenstein, Bavière, Alsace). 
En allemand, et dans la plupart des langues d'origine germanique  la lettre « J » se prononce /j/ (comme le « y » dans yeux)<sup>1</sup>.

La transcription *yass* n'est donc qu'une adaptation phonétique de la graphie du son /j/ à la prononciation du français. La lettre « j » ne se prononcera /y/ en français que dans des mots d’origine germaniques.

D'après mon édition du *[Duden](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duden)* le nom viendrait du néerlandais *jas*. La variante néerlandaise du jeu est le [*Klaverjas*](http://www.jeuxdecartes.net/jeux-cartes/Klaverjas/). *Jas* étant une variante pour [désigner le valet](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klaverjassen) dans le jeu de carte<sup>2</sup>.

<sup>1. La lettre « j » n'a été introduite dans l’alphabet latin qu'au moyen-âge et a donné la prononciation /ʒ/ en français (comme dans jeu et bouger).</sup>
<sup>2.En français un [jacque](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/jacques) était un sobriquet donné aux paysans. En anglais le valet du jeu de carte se dit *jack*.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Quelques autres mots où le « j » conserve comme dans « jasser » sa prononciation originale germanique :

- jodler : vocaliser à la manière des tyroliens
- jonkheer : titre nobilaire néerlandais
- jungien: relatif au psychanalyste Karl Gustav Jung

Answer (score 0):

Le verbe *jasser* vient du nom du jeu de cartes [*Jass*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jass) (jeu de cartes très populaire en Suisse, qui se prononce d'ailleurs *yass*). Ce mot vient de l'allemand est dans cette langue le *j* se prononce comme un *y* (en français). De là, tout le monde prononce *jasser* à la façon de *yasser*.

Je n'ai pas d'autres exemples, mais il existe certainement d'autres mots provenant de l'allemand ou d'autres langues où le *j* se prononce comme dans la langue d'origine.