# Le verbe « jasser » en français québécois

Tags: étymologie, québec

Les recherches que j'ai faites à propos de cette [autre question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/11303/358) m'ont conduit à m’interroger sur le verbe *jasser* tel qu'il est employé au Québec.

On trouve sur le [wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/jasser) :

> jasser /ʒa.se/
>   1. *(Canada)* Bavarder.

Je n'ai trouvé ce mot que dans des forums, par exemple :

> je cherche personne pour jasser de tout et de rien  [[...]](http://www.jecontacte.com/profil/nanie6923)
>
> j'ai jassé hier avec le proprio de chez Marina Bo-bi-no à Laval et il me disait qu'il ferait [[...]](http://www.motoneigeauquebec.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-120965.html?s=54c03dfbdd14a6a5d835d8c0feed756d)
>
> j'ai jassé avec des résident  [[...]](http://www.quebecpeche.com/forums/index.php?/topic/62026-du-gouffre/page-8)

**1.** Ce mot *jasser* est-il répandu au Québec ? Ou bien est-il utilisé de façon très locale ?

**2.** Ce verbe aurait-il son origine dans une orthographe défectueuse du verbe *jaser* /ʒɑ.ze/ que les québécois emploient avec le sens de [discuter](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/jaser) ? Mais dans ce cas comment expliquer le passage de la prononciation /s/ à /z/ ?

L’orthographe s'est-elle adaptée à une variante peut-être locale de la prononciation du mot *jaser* qui serait /ʒa.se/ ?

Comment: Au Québec, nous utilisons *jaser* assez souvent comme synonyme de *parler*,  *bavarder* ou *discuter*. Cependant, je n'ai jamais entendu le mot *jasser* de ma vie. Donc je ne crois pas qu'il soit répandu. Je n'ai aucune idée du changement de prononciation de /s/ à /z/.

Comment: Le problème avec l'historique de la prononciation (selon moi) est qu'il est très difficile de retracer les raisons de leur modifications. C'est comme le mot [poteau](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4777). Juste au Québec, il y deux prononciations différentes dépendant de la région ([pOto] ou [poto]). Je ne vois pas non plus de lien tangible entre *jaser* et un mot anglais. Donc je vois pas comment on pourrait déterminer la raison de la modification de *jasser* à *jaser* (on peut probablement lier ces deux mots ensemble vu leur ressemblance frappante).

Comment: je vis au Québec depuis dix ans, je n'ai jamais vu jasser avec deux ss. Avec deux ss on ne peut pas prononcer en Z en français. Par contre tout le monde utilise le mot jaser pour "bavarder, clavarder". C'est très courant, même dans un milieu de travail. C'est un niveau courant de langue, ni élevé, ni familier, à mon avis. Le wikitionaire cite un forum...probablement une erreur typographique de celui qui a posté le message.

Comment: @JoBedard Je l'ai trouvé sur beaucoup d'autres forums, c'est pour ça que j'ai posé la question. C'est visiblement très familier et je me demande si ce ne pourrait pas être régional ?

Comment: @Laure Le mot existe aussi en français de France avec des sens très proches: http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/jaser

Comment: @JoBedard: C'est *jaser* qui existe en français, mais *jasser* sur lequel je pose ma question est un tout autre mot (ça veut dire jouer au [jas](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/11306/358) ).

Comment: @Laure, étant donnée que vous avez seulement trouvé l'orthographe avec un double 's' dans des forums écrits et les autres commentaires sur cette question, peux t'on en déduire qu'il s'agit de fautes commises par les intervenants?

Comment: @DavidSegonds Je ne déduis rien, j'attends de voir si un québécois (encore très très peu nombreux sur ce site) tombera un jour sur la question. Par contre c'est ce que j'envisage dans la question (2), et bien sûr avec le pourquoi de la prononciation signalée dans le wiktionnaire.

Comment: If research could show that evidence of local usage (if any) is coming predominantly from Quebecois of German ethnicity (there are about 84,000 in the Montreal area), then perhaps an argument could be made that this alternative spelling and pronunciation come from their hearing and pronouncing the word as if it were spelled with an "eszett" (ß), and for lack of an “ß” on their keyboards (or out of support of the 1996 spelling reform [poor "eszett," I knew him well!]), they use the “double S.”  (Curiously, one of the answers to the question that you cite ["y"or"j"] also mentions Germanic roots)

Comment: Ils avaient peut-être confondu avec _javasser_ (Poitou ; voir [_Glossaire du parler français au Canada_](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf), 1930), pas davantage en usage aujourd'hui. Merci.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sincèrement, j'habite au Québec et entre amis ou même entre professionnelles, nous jasons, prononcé comme jazons.

Bavardé va aussi être utilisé et c'est à mon avis dans les mêmes circonstances quoique beaucoup moins usuel.

Je n'ai jamais personnellement employé "jassé" ni même entendu ça. Du moins, autant que je saches. Je sais aussi qu'il y a beaucoup de variances selon les régions et ici, en Mauricie au Québec, c'est «jasé» et je dirais même que c'est «jâsé».

> « J'ai vu Claude hier et il m'a *jâsé* ça. ».

Autre exemple de comment nous l'utilisons

> « J'ai vu Claude hier et nous nous sommes "pické" une petite *jâsette*. »

Il est rare que nous utilisons clavardons tel que suggéré par Jo Bedard outre que dans un contexte virtuel, sur internet.

Source : http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/jaser

Comment: Ceci confirme et me porte donc à croire que les quelques occurrences de *jasser* au sens de « jaser » trouvées sur des forums québécois ne sont qu'une faute d'orthographe, malencontreusement reprise par le [witionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/jasser).

Comment: @Lauce Effectivement, je serais porté à dire que ce sont des fautes d'orthographe.

Comment: Et je tiens à dire que je suis désolé car je ne suis pas au courant exactement de comment fonctionne les "/ʒa.se/", comme mentionné dans la question initial. Alors si quelqu'un peu éditer ma réponse, libre à vous.

Comment: @SimonDugré, il s'agit de l'[Alphabet phonétique international](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet_phon%C3%A9tique_international).

Answer (score 2):

En français on trouve le nom de « jasse » (ou parfois écrit « ajasse »). Ce terme désigne une pie. Il est originaire du vieux français et on le trouve utilisé en langue d'oïl et en langue d'oc. Ce terme est encore utilisé tant dans les régions de langues occitane (partie sud de la France) que dans celles de langue d'oïl, notamment en Limagne et en Poitou. La pie est un oiseau bruyant et bavard. En français, on utilise l'expression « pie bavarde » ou on dit parfois d'une personne qu'elle est « bavarde comme une pie ». Il se pourrait bien que ce nom de jasse lié au comportement bavard de l'oiseau qu'il désigne ait donné naissance au verbe *jasser*.

Answer (score 0):

*Jasser* n'existe pas dans n'importe quelle parlure québécoise ou acadienne. C'est clair. On dit et on écrit *jaser*.
En Suisse, il y a un jeu de carte, le yass, ou le jass. Jasser veut dire probablement jouer au jass, comme on dirait familièrement beloter pour jouer  la belote.
Mes 2 centimes...